# keep values from dictionary that are not in list

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

I have a list `val`

```
val = ['ed2', 'll', 'mal', 'DC', 'sp3', 'oo']
```

and a dictionary `d`

```
d = {'A': ['2500ed2', '545ll', 'fine', '340DC'], 'B': ['Q5mal', 'fern','2DC', '2mal', 'fist', 'Q12mal']}
```

I would like to skip any strings ending with any of the values contained in `val` e.g. `2500ed2` would be skipped since it ends with `ed2` but `fine` would be kept in the final dictionary because it doesn't end in any of the values in `val`. I would like my final output to be

```
d = {'A': ['fine'],'B': ['fern','fist']}
```

I have tried the following but this doesn't quite work

```
d = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = [n for n in v if n not in val]
```

How do I change my loop to get my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `endswith()`:

```py
d = { k:[ev for ev in v if not any(ev.endswith(x) for x in val)]
      for k,v in d.items() }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can a list comprehension, with `endswith()`:

```
result = {}
for key, value in d.items():
    result[key] = [s for s in value if not any(s.endswith(v) for v in val)]
```

Per @ShadowRanger, you can improve this by converting `val` to a tuple before entering the loop. This means you don't need a generator or list comprehension to iterate over `val`, as `endswith()` can take a tuple as its argument:

```
result = {}
val = tuple(val)
for key, value in d.items():
    result[key] = [s for s in value if not s.endswith(val)]
```

Comment: You don't need an explicit list inside the `any`. Using a generator is more efficient.

Comment: Even better: Convert `val` to a `tuple` (outside the loop for performance), e.g. `val = tuple(val)`, and you can just do `if not s.endswith(val)`; `endswith` can take a `tuple` of endings to check, and does the same work as `any(s.endswith(v) for v in val)`, but more efficiently (no need to create Python generators, call `any`, call `endswith` multiple times, etc.).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Wow, I didn't know `endswith()` could take a tuple for its argument, thanks for the advice! Updated my answer.