# use list to eliminate values from dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, loops, dictionary

I have a list

```
val = ['ed2', 'LL', 'mal', 'DC', 'sp3', 'oo']
```

And a dictionary

```
d = {'A': ['25ed2ish', '5LL45', 'fine', 'LL24'], 'B': ['Q5maDC', 'fern', 'fist', 'Q12malRights']}
```

I would like to skip any strings that have any of the values contained in `val`. e.g. `25ed2ish'` would be skipped since it contains `ed2` in the **middle** of the string. `fine` would be kept in the final dictionary because it doesn't end in any of the values in `val`. I would like my final output to be

```
d = {'A': ['fine','LL24'], 'B': ['Q5maDC','fern', 'fist']}
```

From  [keep values from dictionary that are not in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895729/keep-values-from-dictionary-that-are-not-in-list) I have tried

```
result = {}
val = tuple(val)
for key, value in d.items():
    result[key] = [s for s in value if not val]
```

But this results in

```
{'A': [], 'B': []}
```

How do I tweak my code to achieve my desired output?

Comment: Why did you eliminate `Q5maDC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not comparing the value with `val` anywhere in your code. Try this:

```
result[key] = [s for s in value if not any(v in s and not s.startswith(v) and not s.endswith(v) for v in val)]
```

this will result in:

```
{'A': ['fine', 'LL24'], 'B': ['Q5maDC', 'fern', 'fist']}
```